# Delete all search response documents

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using nest for elasticsearch I am trying to delete an exact number of documents (the oldest I can find) from my index. My mapped object has a TimeStamp field. Only way I managed to make this work is by searching for these documents and then running a foreach over every hit and passing the ID of that hit into the delete API and removing them one by one:

```
var searchResponseAsc = client.Search<MyPersonalObject>(s => s.Sort(sd => sd.Ascending(e => e.TimeStamp)).Take(NumberOfDocumentsToBeDeleted));

foreach (IHit<MyPersonalObject> hit in searchResponseAsc.Hits) {
    client.DeleteByQuery<MyPersonalObject>(dbq => dbq.Index(IndexName).Query(q => q.Ids(s => s.Values(hit.Id))));
}
```

Is there a way to call the delete API on a bulk of search response or even better to nest the search query directly into the delete query?

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: you need to make time based infices such as per day index and then use curator to delete old indices

Comment: I dont see this in the delete APi ,  one thing u can do is to reindex the data you want to keep into other index and then delete the old index , in the reindex u can plug queries

Answer (score 1):

You can embed an Elasticsearch search query in the [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) API:

```
POST twitter/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "message": "some message"
    }
  }
}
```